# Api is not showing serialized json output

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, web-services

I have created simple login screen attached with loginViewController.swift. Here are the urls

```
let login_url        = "http://192.168.100.11:9000//users/authenticate"
let checksession_url = "http://192.168.100.11:9000//users/authenticate"
```

I have simple login api. The web service it is showing response on post man web service but it is not displaying serialized json output on Xcode. How to get serialize json from url?

The api is getting two parameters from username="andrews" and password="admin2"

```
func login_now(username:String, password:String){
        let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
        post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "password")

        let url:URL = URL(string: login_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        var paramString = ""


        for (key, value) in post_data {
            paramString =  paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        }
        let endIndex = paramString.index(paramString.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
        let truncated = paramString.substring(to: endIndex)
        paramString=truncated
        print(paramString)    // This won't consist of last &
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }



            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
//////////////here json object is not formed to get json output


                print("abc")
                print(json)
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }


            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    self.login_session = session_data

                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
                }
            }



        })

        task.resume()


    }
```

Here json object is not formed to get serialized json output.how to get the serialized json out put on Nslog? You can download the project from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xEC2vqv1GOjl8esqqTiSQbpgTTs1MKym/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: This is the same horrible code as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49407802/2227743. Please people, **stop using this abominable tutorial**. Code like `guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response` makes no sense whatsoever. Use better examples, there's many.

Comment: i am using this tutorial http://www.kaleidosblog.com/how-to-create-a-login-screen-page-in-swift-3-authenticate-an-user-and-keep-the-session-active

Comment: Yes, I know which one it is. It's an horrible, horrible tutorial. I don't understand how it became ranked so high in Google's results. It's a very stupid piece of code. Don't use it.